Blender Cycle Render Issue
Having a issue with Cycle Render Blender 4.2 Vers;
Last time it was default to 514 in Max Setting in Render, however, that took rendering for approximately 7 minutes. So I put it down to 8 in Max Setting and took about 3 or 4 minutes. Did googled how to render Cycle Faster, however none of those setting were working and GPU with either CUDA or OptiX causing the "CUDA is illegal" errors.
I dont know whats else to do with rendering the entire 620 frames and 2000 frames in animation.


What GPU do you have? What errors do you get exactly? Also noise threshold at 1 is ridiculously too much, and 8 samples isn't going to look good even with denoising unless you render a simple cube.

@Lauloque
I got "failed retain CUDA Context (illegal address)" whenever I tried to render with GPU. Has NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti.
Why 1 noise threshold too much? It worked before and now its getting slower.
Im trying to render the burger in restaurant ...

For your error, check this topic. there are many answers that could help, most important one probably being to reinstall your ghraphics drivers. Though with your GPU you would have better performance from Optix instead of CUDA.

For the noise threshold, see Sampling - Blender 4.2 Manual.

If you keep encountering such errors, please see Where to Report a Bug.  For tips on faster Cycles render, see How to render a scene faster in Cycles? - Blender Stack Exchange
